# Inserting Increasing Numbers in SQL

Tags: python, sql

Does SQL have a function similar to the range function in python that will generate a set of increasing numerics? I am aware of the identity function, but I don't want to keep on creating and recreating tables just so I can get a set of increasing numbers.

Ultimately, I want to be able to dynamically create a range of numbers based on the results of a search function, eg

`count(*) from teams where team= 'knicks'`

would give me a number, say 20

an then I dynamically use that number as part of a function

`function(20) ---> 1,2,3,4,5,6... 20`

I want to use the result of the function to have a sorted table where each number corresponds to a player. I can't use identity here, because I'm keeping all the teams in one table, and I'll use the team name to pull out numbered team lists.

Still shakey on how to use stackoverflow's designing, so please bear with.

Comment: What RDBMS?  There's at least two or three potential ways to deal with this: 1) Recursive CTE, 2) UDF that returns a table, 3) number table.  What is the query you're planning on using the numbers _in_?

Comment: The most plausable solution would be to use a window function like rank() or row_number(). BTW: mysql does not seem to have window functions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SQL SEQUENCE. For example [this](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-createsequence.html) guide.

/edit: i´ve read it again, and maybe you should try to make better design of DB. Use normalizations... I don't really understand this sentence:

> I want to use the result of the function to have a sorted table where
>   each number corresponds to a player.

Comment: Actually, no, sequence is what I wanted. Everything else was kinda confusing, I just wanted a range(x,y) function. I'm looking through google, is there a way to set the sequence back to the beginning? eg. if the next value is 45, rest it back to 1?

Comment: Nope, i´m sorry. You can just go forward. Sequence is generally used for purpose of IDs (for example).

Comment: Ah ok. I'm getting around that by just creating and dropping a sequence within a loop. Thanks for the help!